# Ruby script - does not print 'Hello world!' from the command line

Tags: ruby

I have the following code in the script `a.rb`.

```
def main
  puts "Hello World!"
end
```

When I run `ruby a.rb` on the command line, it doesn't display anything.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unlike languages like C/C++/Java, Ruby does't have a `main` method that's called at program startup. The name `main` is not special.

You defined a method named `main`, but never call<sup>1</sup> it.

```
def main
  puts "Hello World!"
end

main # here, call the method
```

<sub>1: Technically, *calling methods* should be called *sending messages*, the idea comes from Smalltalk.</sub>

Comment: For clarity, you don't have to define `main` at all if you don't want to. Your script could have one line containing simply: `puts "Hello World!"`

Comment: You defined a *method* called `main`, there are no functions in Ruby. Also, we don't talk about "calling methods" in Ruby, we talk about "sending messages".